# Scala: How to insert SubClass instead of Superclass in Map declared for SuperClass

Tags: scala, class

I have a requirement to use a Subclass in a HashMap which has been declared for SuperClass. 
For Example: I created a Superclass and a Subclass. 
Now I create a abstract class A and a concrete class B which extends A.
A has a variable myMap which as declared as `java.util.Map[_ <: Superclass, String]` . In class B, I need to use myMap , but I need to insert instance of SubClass instead of Superclass in myMap.following is the code to explain

```
abstract class Superclass {
    def foo(value:String): Boolean
}



class Subclass extends Superclass {
    def foo(value:String) = {
        true // or random boolean expression
    }
}

abstract class A {
    var myMap: java.util.Map[_ <: Superclass, String]
    def addToMap(value:String)
}

class B extends A {
    myMap = new java.util.HashMap[Subclass, String]()

    def addToMap(value:String) { 
        val subclass = new SubClass()
        myMap.put(subclass, value) // getting compilation error here
    }
}
```

If i try to insert Subclass instance in myMap, I get following error:
type mismatch; found : Subclass.type (with underlying type Subclass) required: _$2 where type _$2 <: SuperClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could use `SubClass` here, you would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle: Class `B` should be able to do everything which can be done with `A`, but in your example, you can't stuff `SuperClass` keys in its `Map`.

There are several ways around it, e.g. you could parametrize `A` and `B`:

```
abstract class A[S <: Superclass] {
  var myMap: java.util.Map[S, String]

  def addToMap(value: String)
}

class B extends A[Subclass] {

  var myMap:java.util.Map[Subclass, String] = new java.util.HashMap[Subclass, String]()

  def myMap(map: java.util.Map[Subclass, String]) { myMap = map }

  def addToMap(value: String) {
    val subclass = new Subclass()
    myMap.put(subclass, value)
  }
}
```

A similar solution could use abstract type members instead:

```
abstract class A {

  type S <: Superclass

  var myMap: java.util.Map[S, String]

  def addToMap(value: String)
}

class B extends A {

  type S = Subclass

  var myMap: java.util.Map[Subclass, String] = new java.util.HashMap[Subclass, String]()

  def myMap(map: java.util.Map[Subclass, String]) {
    myMap = map
  }

  def addToMap(value: String) {
    val subclass = new Subclass()
    myMap.put(subclass, value)
  }
}
```

I'm not sure, why the additional setter is required.

Generally, I think putting an `var` in a abstract class is not a good idea. Should an implementation detail leak out like this? Probably not. And even if it is needed, do you really have to be able *replace* the complete map? If not, you can use a `val`. Or you could build a facade for adding, removing, querying elements using `def`s, without mentioning the map at all in `A`.

Comment: Thanks , but i am still getting a error . A different one now . 
At class B definition location it says: class B needs to be abstract, since variable myMap in class A of type java.util.Map[Subclass,String] is not defined (Note that variables need to be initialized to be defined)

Comment: Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Fixed it. I'm not sure why `var` is needed in `B`, but it seems to work now.

Comment: in the abstract class the var could be defined as a def. Then the same overridden declaration could be declared as a val in the subclass